# backface visibility not working in safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am trying to uss cssflip animation in my code in which the element rotates when hovered upon. I have used transition and backface-visibilty property. It is working fine on chrome but it is not working properly on safari. I have used webkit prefix as well for safari browser.

`.card-container{

```
margin-top: 9%;
perspective: 900px;
-webkit-perspective: 900px;
z-index: 1;
```

}

.card{

```
float: left;
width: 78.5%;
height: 35%;
margin-top: 25%;
border: 1px solid #A08C87;
transition: all 0.6s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

}

#front #back{

```
color: white;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

}

## front{

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

}

## back{

```
display: flex;
backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
font-size: 20px;
```

}
.card-container:hover .card{

```
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

}

## back{

```
transform: rotateY(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

}`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think the issue here is with the

```
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

It's not being supported in ios and in safari.

In your code just replace the code with

```
 #front #back {
    color: white;
    -webkit-perspective: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    visibility:visible;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this works. Tested on Safari Version 12.1.1 (14607.2.6.1.1)

Comment: FWIW, years later, `backface-visibility` is not unprefixed in Safari for no reason. WebKit bug is here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=170983

Comment: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; works in older Safari browsers

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for posting this!  I needed to add `!important` and only needed the `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;` when using with tailwind.

Comment: This seemed to regress in iOS17, at least in a certain circumstance which I can't exactly reproduce minimally. Adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;` fixed it as stated above.