# I get an error while opening angular web application on safari 15 browser

Tags: css, angular, safari

Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The animation trigger "angularAnimation" has failed to build due to the following errors: - The provided animation property "backface-visibility" is not a supported CSS property for animations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [backface visibility not working in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744573/backface-visibility-not-working-in-safari)

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing when using the material password-strength extension. There is a suggestion on how to work around this in the bug for this:

https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/password-strength/issues/337