# Why is my login page not formatted correctly on safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

My login page contains both the login form and the sign up form. The two components flip back and forth depending on which one you click. When I view the page on safari, both of the components bleed through and it looks like a jumbled mess. Not sure what the issue is, because it looks fine on all other browsers.

Safari View

[image]

Chrome View. This is what it's supposed to look like.

[image]

This is my code

```css
.login-box {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 525px;
    min-height: 670px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(156,173,183,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 12px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .19);
}

.login-snip {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 90px 70px 50px 70px;
    background: rgba(156,173,183,0.2);
}

.login-snip .login,
.login-snip .sign-up-form {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .4s linear
}

.login-snip .sign-in,
.login-snip .sign-up,
.login-space .group .check {
    display: none
}

.login-snip .tab,
.login-space .group .label,
.login-space .group .button {
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.login-snip .tab {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent
}

.login-snip .sign-in:checked+.tab,
.login-snip .sign-up:checked+.tab {
    color: #fff;
    border-color: #1161ee
}

.login-space {
    min-height: 345px;
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1000px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d
}

.login-space .group {
    margin-bottom: 15px
}

.login-space .group .label,
.login-space .group .input,
.login-space .group .button {
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    display: block
}

.login-space .group .input,
.login-space .group .button {
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)
}

.login-space .group input[data-type="password"] {
    -webkit-text-security: circle
}

.login-space .group .label {
    color: #aaa;
    font-size: 12px
}

.login-space .group .button {
    background: #1161ee
}

.login-space .group label .icon {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1)
}

.login-space .group label .icon:before,
.login-space .group label .icon:after {
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s
}

.login-space .group label .icon:before {
    left: 3px;
    width: 5px;
    bottom: 6px;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(0)
}

.login-space .group label .icon:after {
    top: 6px;
    right: 0;
    transform: scale(0) rotate(0)
}

.login-space .group .check:checked+label {
    color: #fff
}

.login-space .group .check:checked+label .icon {
    background: #1161ee
}

.login-space .group .check:checked+label .icon:before {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(45deg)
}

.login-space .group .check:checked+label .icon:after {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg)
}

.login-snip .sign-in:checked+.tab+.sign-up+.tab+.login-space .login {
    transform: rotate(0)
}

.login-snip .sign-up:checked+.tab+.login-space .sign-up-form {
    transform: rotate(0)
}


a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none
}

.divide{
    height: 2px;
    margin: 60px 0 50px 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)
}

.foot {
    text-align: center
}

::placeholder {
    color: #b3b3b3
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid" style='height: 100%;'>
    <div class="row d-flex" style='height: 100%;'>
        <div style="background-color: #333f48;" class="col-md-7 center">

            <div class="login-box">
                <div class="login-snip"> <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="tab" class="sign-in" checked><label
                        for="tab-1" class="tab">Login</label> <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="tab"
                        class="sign-up"><label for="tab-2" class="tab">Sign Up</label>
                    <div class="login-space">
                        <form action='/login' id="loginData" method="POST">
                            <div class="login">
                                <div class="group"> <label for="user" class="label">Email</label> <input name='email'
                                        id="user" type="text" class="input" placeholder="Enter your email"> </div>
                                <div class="group"> <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label> <input
                                        name='password' id="pass" type="password" class="input" data-type="password"
                                        placeholder="Enter your password"> </div>
                                <div class="group mt-5"> <input type="submit" class="button" value="Sign In"> </div>
                                {{#if error}}
                                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                    {{error}}
                                </div>
                                {{/if}}
                                <div class="divide"></div>
                                <div style='color: white' class="foot"> <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a> </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <div class="sign-up-form">
                            <div class="group"> <label for="user" class="label">Full Name</label> <input name='name'
                                    id="user" type="text" class="input registerName" placeholder="Enter your full name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="group"> <label for="pass" class="label">Email Address</label> <input id="pass"
                                    value='{{email}}' name="email" type="text" class="input registerEmail"
                                    placeholder="Enter your email address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="group"> <label for="pass" class="label">Password</label> <input id="pass"
                                    type="password" name='password' class="input registerPassword" data-type="password"
                                    placeholder="Create your password"> </div>
                            <div class="group"> <label for="pass" class="label">Repeat Password</label> <input id="pass"
                                    type="password" name='password2' class="input password2" data-type="password"
                                    placeholder="Repeat your password"> </div>

                            <div class="group"> <button type="button" class="button button-primary register mt-5">Sign Up</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divide"></div>
                            <div class="registerMessage">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the current generation of iOS and safari support vanilla backface-visibility? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42744573/backface-visibility-not-working-in-safari

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.